# Plot and label lots of box plots for a read.csv file

Tags: r

I am new to R and need to plot boxplots for a excel sheet which has 16 rows and 195 columns. (sorry don't know how to get the data on here for you to see)

I loaded it using read.csv calling it data

then transposed the data using

```
data2 <- setNames(data.frame(t(data[,-1])), name[,1])
```

I have used `boxplot(data name)` and it does not label them and the box is missing.

Any help??

Thanks! in advance!

Comment: If you've `data <- read.csv(...)` you can`dput(data)` to share them and help you better.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  How can I do this? Sorry I am very new to R.

Comment: You have two way: first, put in R  the function `dput()`, and, in the brackets, the name of your data. Reading your question you've done this `data <-read.csv("pathtodata\data.csv"..)`, right? So you have in your environment the object `data`, containing your data. You've to send the command `dput(data)`, put the output in the question. If you cannot publish your data, you have to create some fake data similar in strucure to yours, maybe with command `data.frame()`, if you have a dataframe as data. Lastly, you should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), to help to be helped.